# How can i use a var in c# over {}

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop, var

How can i use a var in c# over {} like:

```
if
{
   var test;
   while
   {
      test = "12345";
      //test is defined
   } 
   var test2 = test;
   //test is undefined
}
```

I do not understand it.

Comment: use the `if` and `while` constructs how they're supposed to be used.

Comment: you can't, the compiler cannot deduce the type without an assignment. either specify it explicitly or use something like `dynamic` if you really need to

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `var` with uninitialized variable because in this case compiler won't know the real type. `var` is syntactic sugar - compiler should decide which type to use and in IL code you will see real type.

If you really want `var` you should initialize it with any value of some type (in your case - `string`):

```
if
{
   var test = String.Empty; // initialize it - now compiler knows type
   while
   {
      test = "12345";
      //test is defined
   } 
   var test2 = test;
   //test is undefined
}
```

Comment: thx, works! love u <3. And in case it is a Int. can i use Int32.Empty or i just use 0?

Comment: @TimerTick, you can use any `int` value (there is no `Int32.Empty`)

Answer (score 1):

Var is not a type, var is a keyword that tells the computer to decide which type fits for your value.

You can use this instead:

```
if
{
   var test = "placeholder";
   while
   {
      test = "12345";
      //test is defined
   } 
   var test2 = test;
   //test is undefined
}
```

Or better yet, just declare a string from the very start, var is meant to be used when you don't know what type you will need at the point of declaration, when you do know the type you better just declare the reference with the proper type.

Edit:
This code works just fine for me (note that in your original code you were missing the condition

```
            if (true)
               {
                string test;
                while (true)
                {
                    test = "12345";
                    //test is defined
                }
                var test2 = test;
                //test is undefined
                }
```

Comment: if i type string test; it does not work, i need a placeholder

Comment: Take a look at what I added to the answer now, you had lots of syntax errors in your original code.

Comment: @TimerTick  Take a note that the while is a loop, unless you have a condition which at some points turns false, your program will always try to declare test as "12345" and never proceed to test2=test;

Answer (score 1):

You can use `object` type instead of `var` then assign `null` as initialization. It will work for `string, int` as you wish.

Please check below:

```
if
{
    object test = null;
    while
    {
        test = "12345";
        //test is defined
    } 
    var test2 = test;
    //test is undefined
}
```

Please check example in [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pVDckp).